# Why are typedef identifiers allowed to be declared multiple times?

Tags: c, typedef, c99, c11

From the C99 standard, 6.7(5):

> A declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of a set of identifiers. A definition of an identifier is a declaration for that identifier that:
>   for an object, causes storage to be reserved for that object;
>   for a function, includes the function body;
>   **for an enumeration constant or typedef name, is the (only) declaration of the identifier.**

If identifiers with `typedef` are in fact definitions, then why are they allowed to be declared more than once? Example:

```
int main()
{
  typedef int x;
  typedef int x;
}
```

Above program compiles with no errors. How is this possible? I was expecting the program to give me a multiple definition error.

Comment: gah! `void main()` -- it's always `int main()`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### C99 is different from C11

The rules change between C99 and C11 (and the C11 rules match the C++ rules, as I understand it).  Note that in both standards, ¶3 is in the Constraints section and ¶5 is in the Semantics section.  That is important for error messages — constraint violations require a diagnostic.

> #### ISO/IEC 9899:1999 [§6.7 Declarations](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.7)

> ¶3 If an identifier has no linkage, there shall be no more than one declaration of the identifier
> (in a declarator or type specifier) with the same scope and in the same name space, except
> for tags as specified in 6.7.2.3.

> 5 A declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of a set of identifiers. A definition
> of an identifier is a declaration for that identifier that:

> - for an object, causes storage to be reserved for that object;
> - for a function, includes the function body;<sup>98)</sup>
> - for an enumeration constant or typedef name, is the (only) declaration of the identifier.

> #### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 [§6.7 Declarations](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7)

> ¶3 If an identifier has no linkage, there shall be no more than one declaration of the identifier
> (in a declarator or type specifier) with the same scope and in the same name space, except
> that:

> - a typedef name may be redefined to denote the same type as it currently does,
>   provided that type is not a variably modified type;
> - tags may be redeclared as specified in 6.7.2.3.

> ¶5 A declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of a set of identifiers. A definition
> of an identifier is a declaration for that identifier that:

> - for an object, causes storage to be reserved for that object;
> - for a function, includes the function body;<sup>119)</sup>
> - for an enumeration constant, is the (only) declaration of the identifier;
> - for a typedef name, is the first (or only) declaration of the identifier.

[Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584518/lundin) [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26240370/why-are-typedef-identifiers-allowed-to-be-declared-multiple-times/26240595?noredirect=1#comment54326844_26240595) that the Standard C Committee's [web site](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/) contains [n1360](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1360.htm), a one page document detailing why this change was made.  Basically: C++ does it; some compilers already do it; it is neither hard to do nor subverting anything to permit (require) it.

### GCC doesn't always enforce the standard

If your code is compiling, then it is being compiled under the C11 rules, or C++ rules.  It is not being compiled under (strict) C99 rules.

Note that sufficiently recent versions of GCC allow the redefinition unless you insist otherwise, but also note the [report](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26240596/15168) by [John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402272/john-bollinger) that GCC 4.4.7 (on an unidentified platform) does not allow the redefinition at all in C99 mode.

Consider the file `retypedef.c`:

```
int main(void)
{
    typedef int x;
    typedef int x;
    x y = 0;
    return y;
}
```

Compiling on Mac OS X 10.9.5 with GCC 4.9.1, I get:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror           -c retypedef.c
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -c retypedef.c
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Werror           -c retypedef.c
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -c retypedef.c
retypedef.c: In function ‘main’:
retypedef.c:4:17: error: redefinition of typedef ‘x’ [-Werror=pedantic]
     typedef int x;
                 ^
retypedef.c:3:17: note: previous declaration of ‘x’ was here
     typedef int x;
                 ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$
```

It doesn't complain unless `-pedantic` is used, and then only if C99 is requested (it is standard compliant to redefine a `typedef` in the same scope in C11).

Comment: Thank you.Your answer covered all the details I required.

Comment: Any idea why this was changed in C11? Just harmonization with C++ or something else?

Comment: @Lundin: I have no specific insight into why.  I would assume it was a combination of 'harmonization with C++' and 'it makes sense and is not hard to support'.  If you wanted to go through the [C standardization committee](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/) notes, I'm sure you could find the reason why — probably looking at minutes and then finding the document, unless there's a working search option.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler [This](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1360.htm) is the closest thing to a rationale I have found. If you wish, feel free to add that link to your answer for completeness :)

Comment: @Lundin: thanks.  See update.  I doubt if it was controversial given that it was a one-page document with prior art and C++ compatibility to support the change (and no danger of breaking existing working code).

Answer (score 2):

Your program compiles without error because your compiler is being lax (or compiling for a different standard).  If I compile your code with gcc 4.4.7 then it in fact does report an error about the redefinition of x.

Comment: So basically in older compiler versions they follow strict C99 rules.
My compiler is a GCC 4.8.1.
Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason that other declarations are allowed to be declared multiple times. For example:

```
void foo(int a);

void foo(int a);

int main()
{
    foo(42);
}

void foo(int a)
{
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

This allows more than one header to declare a function or structure, and allow two or more such headers to be included in the same translation unit.

typedefs are similar to prototyping a function or structure -- they declare identifiers that have some compile time meaning, but no runtime meaning. For example, the following wouldn't compile:

```
int main()
{
    typedef int x;
    typedef int x;
    x = 42;
}
```

because `x` does not name a variable; it is only a compile time alias for the name `int`.

Comment: In fact the quoted section of the standard does say that a typedef declaration is also a definition, and there can only be one _definition_ of any identifier.  gcc reports an error for the OP's code, at least with -Wall -pedantic -std=c99.

Comment: @John: Ah, I guess I spend too much time in C++ land. I'm still leaving the answer though because as Jonathan Leffler indicates, it is correct in C11.