# Can we have two or more typedef from the same struct in C?

Tags: c

Can we have two or more typedef from the same struct in C?

Example:

```
typedef struct word {
  char *letter;
  struct word *next;
} Word;
typedef struct word SequenceL;
typedef Word Something;
```

Comment: apparently [yes](http://ideone.com/bhlagM)

Comment: Yes, all three are allowed to coexist.

Comment: The real question is why?  A single `typedef` can be confusing, so having more than one would be ... ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `typedef` is simply a declaration of an alternative name for an existing type.   There is nothing that prevents multiple typedefs that all declare different alternative names for the same existing type.

There is also nothing that prevents a `typedef` referencing another `typedef` (assuming the compiler has visibility of the first).

So, in

```
 typedef struct foo Foo;
 typedef Foo AnotherFoo;
```

both `Foo` and `AnotherFoo` are alternative names for `struct foo`.

Answer (score 3):

Sure we can. Typedefs don't actually change anything at runtime. The point is, you're not "replacing the declaration of struct word with a better sounding name" but rather "creating a new declaration that acts as if it was struct word"

Comment: This answer is confusing, and references to macros are not appropiate here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes its allowed. Take an example of type int which is a basic primitive type. And often we use typedef to give more contextual names. Something like this ( source wikipedia : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef#Usage_examples)

typedef int km_per_hour ;
typedef int points ;

As you see the type is same but still allowed to typedef differently. Same rule could be applied to more complex structures. Hope you get what i am trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the previous answers are "wrong".  The point is not whether it makes sense or not (of course it does and should pose no problem).  The real point is whether this is *valid* C, as per the standard.

And it turns out that C changed its mind.

It was invalid up to C99, and accepted in C11 onwards.

[Jonathan Leffler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26240595/1353549) describes this perfectly.