# C header files without #ifndef still work...why?

Tags: c

Why don't I get the error messages?
I have three header files named DataType.h, printInt.h, printStr.h, and one myApp.c.

DataType.h

```
    typedef int Integer;
    typedef char String;
```

printInt.h

```
    #include "DataType.h"
    void printInt(Integer);
```

printInt.c

```
    #include "printInt.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    void printInt(Integer number){
        printf("%d\n", number);
    }
```

printStr.h

```
    #include "DataType.h"
    void printStr(String*);
```

printStr.c

```
   #include "printStr.h"
   #include <stdio.h>
   void printStr(String *str){
       printf("%s\n", str);
   }
```

myApp.c

```
    #include "printStr.h"
    #include "printInt.h"
    Integer main(void){
        printInt(20);
        printStr("hello");

        return 0;
    }
```

Clearly, I have included the DataType.h twice, and I did not use #ifndef to avoid redefinition of Integer and String. Please, someone, tell me how I can get the error messages to demonstrate the directive is working properly.

```
   #ifndef __DATATYPE_H
   #define __DATATYPE_H
      typedef int Integer;
      typedef char String;
   #endif
```

Regardless having #ifndef or not, the gcc complier (version 5.4.0) does not generate any error messages. What's wrong?

Comment: `#ifndef __DATATYPE_H` Note: preprocessor macro names with a leading underscore are reserved. Better not use them.

Comment: why not just `#pragma once`

Comment: Why wouldn't they work? They're just declarations. Those can be repeated multiple times in different places with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Definitions of `typedef` and prototypes of functions can occur as many times as you want. For example:

```
typedef int lala;
typedef int lala;

void somePrototype();
void somePrototype();

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

will compile just fine: https://ideone.com/4EjfaR

Try adding the definition of a function to a header file. You will see then that you get a redefinition error and will require a header guard.

Comment: that is: if the declaration is exactly identical.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yeah, which it is and always will be in this example because it is coming from an include.

Comment: not necessarily, because preprocessor directives may be different at the time of inclusions

Comment: and it's not strictly legal in C11 as Johnatan Leffer excellent answer suggests (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26240370/why-are-typedef-identifiers-allowed-to-be-declared-multiple-times)

Comment: Okay! First of all, thank you for all your replies. My bad! I should not use typedef as an example (try to make the programs as smaller as possible).

Comment: Also, I overlooked your answer (the function prototypes can be repeated many times)! It seems I don't have a good example to demonstrate why we should use #ifndef. Can you give me one simple example? Thanks!

Comment: @Toebi `enum X { A };`  cannot be repeated, for instance, and neither can an inline function definition.  And if I'm reading the linked answer correctly, in C99, a duplicate typedef is _not_ allowed (although in many compilers this is only diagnosed with an off-by-default warning) but in C11 it is allowed.